# Entity Framework inserting row with composite key

Tags: entity-framework, composite, savechanges

I am using Entity Framework 4.3.1 and I am trying to insert a new record into the table my `ProductVersion` entity is based on.

The `ProductVersion` entity has 2 properties that make up a composite primary key for the table called `ProductId` and `ProductOrdinal`.

Whenever someone updates a product entry I am creating and passing a `ProductVersion` entity back to my repository, incrementing the `ProductOrdinal` property, and attempting to add the entity to the context and save it.

I keep getting the following error:

> The property 'ProductOrdinal' is part of the object's key information and cannot be modified.

Neither of the columns that make up the key are autonumbering and I have annotated the properties in my POCO with the following:

```
[Key, Column("PROD_Ordinal", Order=2), DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
public long ProductOrdinal { get; set; }
```

Comment: From the exception and your description it seems that you are incrementing the 'ProductOrdinal' property on the existing 'ProductVersion' instance and trying to save it. 

What you probably want to do is create a new instance of 'ProductVersion' from the existing instance and increment the 'ProductOrdinal' property and save the new instance.

Comment: I will check that out. I think you may be right.

Comment: You were absolutely correct. The context was still open so when I updated the "current" object and did my compare as far as it was concerned I had updated the same object and it was complaining that I was trying to update the key that was already inserted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Marc_S was exactly right in his comment as to why this was not working.

From the exception and your description it seems that you are incrementing the 'ProductOrdinal' property on the existing 'ProductVersion' instance and trying to save it. What you probably want to do is create a new instance of 'ProductVersion' from the existing instance and increment the 'ProductOrdinal' property and save the new instance.